# Python Qt/GTK/WxWidgets DataGrid database aware

Tags: python, database, datagrid

Is there any DataGrid/DataGridView component 
part of a GUI components library like Qt/GTK/WxWidgets/etc.
that has the same funcionality and flexibility
as C#/WPF or C#/Winforms DataGridView ?

(mainly for use with Python 3... cross-platform/avoid MS .net)

I mean working in tandem with a Dataset component
or similar paradigm/functionality to implement CRUD ?

I don't want to extend more the question in this phase...
I'll wait for some answers to develop the discussion...

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have never used C#WPF or the other tool you mentioned.

Disclaimer2: This app does not have CRUD, yet. It only has read support.

Finally, there is no guarantee this is even close to what you are looking for. I am posting because it seems nobody has a better solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# sql_window.py

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import psycopg2, sys

class SQLWindowGUI :
    def __init__(self):

        self.db = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'trial_new_db', user = 'postgres', password = 'true', host = '192.168.0.120')
        button = Gtk.Button('Run SQL')
        button.set_property('valign', Gtk.Align.END)
        button.set_property('halign', Gtk.Align.END)
        button.connect('clicked', self.run_sql_clicked)
        overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
        overlay.add_overlay(button)
        self.sql_buffer = Gtk.TextBuffer()
        self.sql_buffer.set_text("SELECT id, name FROM contacts")
        textview = Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer(self.sql_buffer)
        textview.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR)
        overlay.add (textview)
        pane = Gtk.Paned()
        pane.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        pane.set_position(100)
        pane.add1(overlay)
        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
        self.scrolledwindow.add(self.treeview)
        self.sql_error_buffer = Gtk.TextBuffer()
        self.textview = Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer(self.sql_error_buffer)
        self.textview.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR)
        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.pack_start(self.scrolledwindow, True, True, 0)
        box.pack_start(self.textview, True, True, 0)
        pane.add2(box)
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.add(pane)
        self.window.set_title("SQL Window")
        self.window.set_default_size(600, 500)
        self.window.show_all()
        self.window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

    def run_sql_clicked (self, button):
        for column in self.treeview.get_columns():
            self.treeview.remove_column(column)
        start_iter = self.sql_buffer.get_start_iter ()
        end_iter = self.sql_buffer.get_end_iter ()
        string = self.sql_buffer.get_text(start_iter, end_iter, True)
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(string)
        except Exception as e:
            self.sql_error_buffer.set_text(str(e))
            self.textview.set_visible(True)
            self.scrolledwindow.set_visible(False)
            self.db.rollback()
            return
        #probably an UPDATE, report rows affected
        if cursor.description == None: 
            result = "%s row(s) affected" % cursor.rowcount
            self.sql_error_buffer.set_text(result)
            self.textview.set_visible(True)
            self.scrolledwindow.set_visible(False)
            self.db.rollback()
            return
        #create treeview columns and a liststore to store the info
        self.textview.set_visible(False)
        self.scrolledwindow.set_visible(True)
        type_list = list()
        for index, row in enumerate(cursor.description):
            column_name = row.name
            type_ = row.type_code
            if type_ == 23:
                type_list.append(int)
                renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_name, renderer, text=index)
                self.treeview.append_column(column)
                column.set_sort_column_id(index)
            elif type_ == 16:
                type_list.append(bool)
                renderer = Gtk.CellRendererToggle()
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_name, renderer, active=index)
                self.treeview.append_column(column)
                column.set_sort_column_id(index)
            else:
                type_list.append(str)
                renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_name, renderer, text=index)
                self.treeview.append_column(column)
                column.set_sort_column_id(index)
        store = Gtk.ListStore()
        store.set_column_types(type_list)
        self.treeview.set_model(store)
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            # do a convert, cell by cell, to make sure types are correct
            store_row = list()
            for index, element in enumerate(row):
                store_row.append(type_list[index](element))
            store.append (store_row)
        self.db.rollback()
        cursor.close()

def main_gui():

    app = SQLWindowGUI()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    sys.exit(main_gui())
```

History: I created it as an lightweight alternative to PGAdmin to simply view the data in Postgres. It should work on most any Linux distro with psycopg2 and Gtk3 installed. Theoretically, it should be cross-platform.

Comment: thanks for you answer... the goal is also to find what people are using in this area... and provide information for oher...

Comment: I'll this try as soon as I can---